# "browser.text.include?" returning false positives? (watir-webdriver & cucumber)

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, watir-webdriver

Basically I want to check an error message when submitting a form with an empty required field.

```
def usertabfieldvalidation
@session.button(:class, "btn-primary").click
@session.text.include? 'Giant Gerbils of the world unite'
end
```

This step passes. I want to check for the text "Please fill out this field" but any text I look for will pass. I'm fairly new to ruby and watir-webdriver so wondering where I've gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there more code? There are no assertions to trigger a fail.

Comment: That makes sense but I'm not sure how to write that. Could you give me an example of an assertion?

Comment: It depends on what test framework you are using. For example, RSpec would have `expect(@session.text).to include('Please fill out this field')`. In Minitest you would have `assert(@session.text.include?('Please fill out this field'))`. Slightly dated, but the Watir webpage has some examples - http://watir.com/frameworks/.

Comment: Framework is cucumber, I'll take a look at the examples and see what I can find. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I added RSpec to my Gemfile and env.rb.

I was still getting method undefined errors for `expect` because I was calling a method outside of my step definitions.

I added `include RSpec::Matchers` to the class containing the method I wanted and then updated method to

`expect(@session.text).to include('Please fill out this field')`

and that seems to have done the trick. Thanks!